# Kanban labels from trac

Tags: xml, libreoffice, kanban

I want generate kanban labels from [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) tickets.
Trac exports tickets in xml format, so I want generate labels using this file using, for example, Libreoffice.
I want print labels, because I prefer physical slate.

Is this possible? Are there better solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a solution which is both open source and would interact with Trac tickets. It's called JimFlow and can be found here:

http://jimflow.jimdo.com/

Some benefits of it for you are.

- Print tickets directly out of the ticket system
- Supports flow boards with columns
- Take photos in custom intervals
- Generate digital version of the board with ticket title and type
- Update ticket in ticket system on movement

Overall, it will allow you manage your Trac Kanban board virtually and your physical real world board simultaneously.

Comment: I't a good solution, but we use www.repositoryhosting.com and we can't install plugins.